# Is there a way to use cor function with factor variables without creating dummy variables? (R)

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dataset with several categorical predictors with varying factor levels. Is there a way to generate a correlation matrix from this data without having to create a bunch of dummy variables?

I'm using multiple linear regression to predict a continuous variable (sales). The predicted values are surprisingly accurate and plotting the predicted vs observed results in a near diagonal line.

I thought that was all I needed to worry about, but in researching, I found I should also plot predicted vs residuals to test for homoscedasticity. I did that and found out I was violating it.

I was looking for a way to resolve this and found a post that said I should use a robust method for computing the covariance matrix. Hence why I want to use the `cor()` function, though I’m not sure if that’s actually the right way of going about this.

And here are the actual graphs:

Predicted vs Actual...

[image]

Predicted vs Residual...

[image]

Comment: What do you want the correlation matrix *for*? What would be the problem w/ creating sets of dummy variables?

Comment: To start, I am extremely new to all of this, so forgive my ignorance. I'm using multiple linear regression to predict a continuous variable (sales). The predicted values are surprisingly accurate and plotting the predicted vs observed results in a near diagonal line. 
I thought that was all I needed to worry about, but in researching, I found I should also plot predicted vs residuals to test for homoscedasticity. I did that and found out I was violating it.
I was looking for a way to resolve this and found a post that said I should use a robust method for computing the covariance matrix.

Comment: Hence why I want to use the cor function, though I’m not sure if that’s actually the right way of going about this.
As for the problem with creating dummy sets, there’s no issue, and I’ll do that if there’s no other way. I was just curious if it was possible without doing that. @gung

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but here are the graphs: Predicted vs actual... https://i.imgur.com/nvvgVSQ.png..... And predicted vs residuals... https://i.imgur.com/uZrigHk.png

Comment: This is good information. I suspect what you have here is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It would be better to edit your Q to talk about your situation & what you are ultimately doing. (To foreshadow, I think you are going down the wrong path w/ trying to compute your own correlation matrix.) It might further help if you could paste in your data, or the plots that are troubling.

Comment: That doesn't look like heteroscedasticity to me; it looks like an outlier.

Comment: @gung For more context, those 20 points are total sales from various items, so hundreds of values have been summed together. I do agree, though, that I think I have an outlier problem, as a few data points are far outside of the normal range. I'm just not sure what to do with them, as some of my research has said to remove outliers and some has said to keep them. Perhaps I should be plotting all of the residuals, instead of summing it up??

Comment: That XY problem diagnosis actually sounds pretty accurate lol. I guess I'm asking a technical question, regarding coding, when I should really be explaining my root issue of the residual plot.

Comment: Posting the additional information & the plots is definitely an improvement. You are more likely to get the information you actually need. This can still be improved. Can you post your data? What are the variables? Is your goal prediction, or to test a scientific hypothesis? Etc.

Comment: @gung Purely prediction. My data is the consumer expenditure survey public-use microdata (https://www.bls.gov/cex/pumd.htm). The variables are various pieces of demographic data (race, age, income, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is simply "is there a way we can run correlations conditional on categorical variables" then yes. The `correlation` package in R makes this fairly easy. I've shown how to do this with R's native `iris` data as an example:

```
library(correlation) # for correlations
library(tidyverse) # for using grouping function

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  correlation()
```

Which gives you this matrix of grouped correlations that don't require dummy coding at all:

```
# Correlation Matrix (pearson-method)

Group      |   Parameter1 |   Parameter2 |    r |        95% CI | t(48) |         p
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setosa     | Sepal.Length |  Sepal.Width | 0.74 | [ 0.59, 0.85] |  7.68 | < .001***
setosa     | Sepal.Length | Petal.Length | 0.27 | [-0.01, 0.51] |  1.92 | 0.202    
setosa     | Sepal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.28 | [ 0.00, 0.52] |  2.01 | 0.202    
setosa     |  Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | 0.18 | [-0.11, 0.43] |  1.25 | 0.217    
setosa     |  Sepal.Width |  Petal.Width | 0.23 | [-0.05, 0.48] |  1.66 | 0.208    
setosa     | Petal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.33 | [ 0.06, 0.56] |  2.44 | 0.093    
versicolor | Sepal.Length |  Sepal.Width | 0.53 | [ 0.29, 0.70] |  4.28 | < .001***
versicolor | Sepal.Length | Petal.Length | 0.75 | [ 0.60, 0.85] |  7.95 | < .001***
versicolor | Sepal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.55 | [ 0.32, 0.72] |  4.52 | < .001***
versicolor |  Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | 0.56 | [ 0.33, 0.73] |  4.69 | < .001***
versicolor |  Sepal.Width |  Petal.Width | 0.66 | [ 0.47, 0.80] |  6.15 | < .001***
versicolor | Petal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.79 | [ 0.65, 0.87] |  8.83 | < .001***
virginica  | Sepal.Length |  Sepal.Width | 0.46 | [ 0.20, 0.65] |  3.56 | 0.003**  
virginica  | Sepal.Length | Petal.Length | 0.86 | [ 0.77, 0.92] | 11.90 | < .001***
virginica  | Sepal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.28 | [ 0.00, 0.52] |  2.03 | 0.048*   
virginica  |  Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | 0.40 | [ 0.14, 0.61] |  3.03 | 0.012*   
virginica  |  Sepal.Width |  Petal.Width | 0.54 | [ 0.31, 0.71] |  4.42 | < .001***
virginica  | Petal.Length |  Petal.Width | 0.32 | [ 0.05, 0.55] |  2.36 | 0.045*   

p-value adjustment method: Holm (1979)
Observations: 50
```

Of course, you will need to run the specifics such as which correlation to use, etc. but this should do the trick. For the follow up questions noted in the comments section of your question, that is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the [lmtest package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/index.html) for re-estimating the model along with the [sandwich package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/index.html) for the robust covariance matrix

```
fit <- lm(sales ~ race + age + ...)

install.packages(sandwich)
install.packages(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

coeftest(fit, vcov = vcovHC(fit, type="HC"))
```

Type "HC" is the original White's estimator, the default in vcovHC is "HC3" and the reason for this is given in the documentation `?vcovHC`